# Could you paraphrase the following sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammar

> an extraordinary story **as** fast-paced **with** **as** much sheer narrative power **as** any novel of recent years.

The three usages of “as” made me get confused, and I don’t why **with** is used with “fast-paced” as long as it is an adjective?

Comment: It's a poorly constructed sentence.  I suppose the author is trying to combine two sentences into one, *"a story as fast-paced as ..."* and *"a story with as much sheer narrative power as ..."*,  but it doesn't really work.  It's a bad idea to sacrifice comprehensibility for brevity.

Comment: OH, I see the problem. as fast-paced  there means: which is as fast-paced as this one and with as much sheer narrative power etc. It's just not great writing. Online writing is often ***poorly edited***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The noun-phrase can be parsed as a noun modified by two as-phrases:

an extraordinary story

```
as fast paced ... [as any novel of recent years]

with as much sheer narrative power  ... as any novel of recent years
```

The prepositional phrase **with as much sheer power** interrupts the first **as fast paced ... as** comparison.

Compare:

```
A tiny flashlight
    as bright, with as much illuminating power, as any search beacon.
```

Normally, we put an **and** in there to make the syntax clearer:

> A tiny flashlight  as bright, **and** with as much illuminating power,
>   as any search beacon.

Comment: A very good explanation.